# Single query for "INSERT INTO table if column value not found"

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

How can I use a single query for inserting table when a column value is not found.
eg/ i want to insert new user only when this username not found

what i doing now is issue 1 query to check for existing,
then another query if no existing found. total 2 query

```
 INSERT INTO friends (memberID) SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT memberID FROM friends WHERE memberID =  1)
```

Comment: you do it with a where not exists clause in the query

Comment: if((select count(*) from tb_user where userName =@userName) = 0 then insert into tb_user(@userName) end if

Comment: Please post your query so far.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: hi added. i using mysql.... the statement i tried not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `FROM DUAL`

```
INSERT INTO friends 
            (memberid) 
SELECT 1 
FROM   dual 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT memberid 
                   FROM   friends 
                   WHERE  memberid = 1)
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bf46/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (UserName)
SELECT x
FROM (SELECT 'New User Name' AS x) a
      WHERE x NOT IN(SELECT UserName
                     FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want one row with a given value you should enforce that with a UNIQUE constraint on the table, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE friends ADD UNIQUE (memberID);
```

After you do that, you can simply add the IGNORE keyword to your insert statements and it won't report an error and it won't insert a duplicate row if it already exists.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO friends(memberID) VALUES(1);
```